# How to remove NA from facet_wrap in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, na, facet-wrap

I am trying to use facet_wrap to make a polygon map in ggplot2. I have two factor levels (soybean, Maize) in my variable "crop" However, I am getting three plots: soybean, maize and one with NA values. In addition NA values are not displayed in the first two facets-

here is my code to make the map:

```
ggplot(study_area.map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=brazil_loss_new2)) + 
  geom_path(colour="black") + 
  facet_wrap(~crop, ncol=2, drop=T) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(na.value="grey", palette="Blues", 
    name="Average production lossess\n per municipality", 
    breaks = levels(study_area.map$brazil_loss_new2), 
    labels = levels(study_area.map$brazil_loss_new2)) + 
  theme() + 
  coord_fixed()
```

and this is what I get:

[image]

If I use na.omit I get the following figure (which is better, but there are still the NA values missing in the first two plots)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3xD3.png)

Including rows for each variable and municipality no matter if the variable of interest is NA or not, finally solves the problem. Here is what I was looking for:

[Yield losses by municipalities with NA values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ua4I.png)

Comment: And what is the output you'd like to see?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the NA's in place while calling the ggplot function. Remove the NA's in the core data function. That way it wont plot them

```
ggplot(data = study_area.map[!(is.na(study_area.map[$brazil_loss_new2)),], 
       aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))+ 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=brazil_loss_new2))+ 
  geom_path(colour="black")+ 
  facet_wrap(~crop, ncol=2, drop=T)+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(na.value="grey", palette="Blues", 
                    name="Average production lossess\n per municipality", 
                    breaks =levels(study_area.map$brazil_loss_new2), 
                    labels=levels(study_area.map$brazil_loss_new2))+ 
  theme()+ 
  coord_fixed()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does including `na.omit()` around the data call get you what you want?

```
ggplot(na.omit(study_area.map), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=brazil_loss_new2)) + 
  geom_path(colour="black") + 
  facet_wrap(~crop, ncol=2, drop=T) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(na.value="grey", palette="Blues", 
    name="Average production lossess\n per municipality", 
    breaks = levels(study_area.map$brazil_loss_new2), 
    labels = levels(study_area.map$brazil_loss_new2)) + 
  theme() + 
  coord_fixed()
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @phalteman! However, it does not solve the problem completly. Using na.omit gives a facet map without the NA plot, but now I am missing polygons with NA values in the first two plots

Comment: @albren, Ok, so can you edit your question to be more specific about what output you'd like to see? (i.e., maize and soybean plots, with NA values in one or the other? in both? divided up somehow between them?)

Comment: I finally made it. The problem was in the dataframe itself: there needs to be one row for each crop and municipality no matter if the variable (here production loss) is NA or not. My dataframe did not contain rows for NA values. Sorry for my bad explanation and unspecific question  :/

Comment: @albren, Glad you solved it. Feel free to post your solution as an answer and accept it so that others can benefit from what you learned.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but in the event someone still needs an answer, the easiest way to remove the crop = NA plot would be to filter that out before piping to ggplot.

```
df  %>% 
filter(!is.na(crop)) %>% 
ggplot...
```

Answer (score -1):

I was running the following code with the same issue and simply adding `na.omit()` worked for me:

````
ggplot(data = mma_male_df) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut(date, "12 months"), fill=method_new)) +
  facet_wrap(~division, ncol = 4, drop = T) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) format(as.Date(x), "%Y")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
  labs(title = "Men's MMA Fights by Year and Outcome", x = "Year", y = "Number of Fights", fill = "Fight Outcome")```

----------

ggplot(data = na.omit(mma_male_df)) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut(date, "12 months"), fill=method_new)) +
  facet_wrap(~division, ncol = 4, drop = T) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) format(as.Date(x), "%Y")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
  labs(title = "Men's MMA Fights by Year and Outcome", x = "Year", y = "Number of Fights", fill = "Fight Outcome")
````

Comment: The OP stated `na.omit()` was not a solution as the NA objects needed to be included in the output.